# How to understand the information entropy calculation in entropy weight method?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, entropy, information-criteria

I found the input of information entropy calculation in the entropy weight method is not probabilities. I can not understand why it works.

In most entropy weight method introductions, the information entropy calculation is as follows
Calculate the relative weight of each sample for each criterion:

\begin{equation}
p_{ij} = \frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}}
\end{equation}

Calculate the information entropy:

\begin{equation}
e_j = -\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}\ln(p_{ij} ) 
\end{equation}

where equation (1) is not a probability.

For example, in a binary classification problem (two classes), a dataset with a 50/50 split of samples for the two classes, would have a maximum entropy, whereas an imbalanced dataset with a split of 10/90 would have a smaller entropy as it is more concentrated. But using the above equations,

if $x = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]$

and $p_{ij} = [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0,0,0,0,0]$

\begin{equation}
e_j = -\frac{1}{\ln(10)}\times 5\times 0.2\ln(0.2) = 0.699
\end{equation}

if $x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]$

and $p_{ij} = [1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,0]$

\begin{equation}
e_j = -\frac{1}{\ln(10)}\times 9\times 1/9\ln(1/9) = 0.954
\end{equation}

The concentrated distribution has larger $e_j$.

From my previous understanding, the information entropy should be calculated as

for $x = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]$

\begin{equation}
e_j = -2\times 0.5\ln(0.5) = 0.693
\end{equation}

for $x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]$

\begin{equation}
e_j = - (0.9\ln(0.9))+0.1\ln(0.1)) = 0.325
\end{equation}

Their results are opposite, so which information entropy calculation is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you point out arises from the different distributions used for calculating the entropy in the two approaches. The entropy weight method uses the distribution of the relative signal strenghts (where I call $x_{ij}$ a signal), whereas the second calculation uses a probability distribution. Both approaches rest on the same idea of concentration and none is more correct than the other.

Let me illustrate with a non-binary example where $x= [1, 2, 3]$. In this case, the entropy weight method uses $p= [1/6, 1/3, 1/2]$. Seeing the $x$ as coming from a distribution (your second way of calculating) we would have to use $p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]$ to calculate the entropy as every value appears just once. The *types* of different signals is completely uniform (each appears once), whereas the *strength* of the signals is very uneven. The entropy weight method wants to measure the latter, i.e. variation in signal strength.

In cases where the $p_{ij}$ are not probabilities, there is no real physical interpretation of the calculation. It is just the same principle as for distributions transferred to a broader setting.

This can lead to some problems due to unnatural weighting. This is discussed in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9317321/) for example (where the method you describe is called EWM-A) where the entropy weight method is used to weigh different models according to the errors they made on past data. To calculate such weights, one uses the entropy formula for values which are not probabilities. This might not be very intuitive, but luckily other weighting approaches exist.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response！

Comment: But I still can not understand the physical background of equation (2) if pij is not probabilities. It seems that most applications of the entropy weighting method do not have prediction errors?

Comment: @Alex I think I misunderstood your question a bit and now edited my answer. When it comes to a physical interpretation, I think it is hard to find one.

Comment: Thanks again！ This is what I want to ask. 
So is it correct to understand that the entropy calculation here is just a borrowed expression without clear basis? Therefore, for similar purpose, something，such as normalized standard deviation also can be used  to calculate weights, and there is no way to compare which weighting method is more reasonable.

Comment: @Alex You could see it like this, yes. Also, if you find the answer helpful, consider accepting it.  Thank you for the positive feedback.